# Including ImGui, GLFW, and GLEW in Premake5

Tags: c++, build, premake

I am writing a C++ program using premake5 as my build system and I cannot understand how to link these libraries together. I want to use ImGui using GLFW and GLEW, but as I port my program over from cmake to premake, I find myself having trouble getting the libraries to link. I am getting LNK2019 and LNK2001 errors for the opengl functions I am using in my program. I know the problem is that the definitions for these functions are not being linked to my program. But as far as I understand premake, I should be doing just that.

Following the example of other premake projects I have found on GitHub, I am making individual projects for each of my dependencies. These projects are forked from the version of the library I am using and added to my git repo via submodules. The premake files for each of the dependencies are as follows:

**premake5.lua (GLEW)**

```
project "GLEW"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files { "include/GL/*.h", "premake5.lua"}
    
    filter "configurations:Debug"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "on"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "on"
```

**premake5.lua (GLFW)**

```
project "GLFW"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files { "include/**.h" }


    filter "configurations:Debug"
            runtime "Debug"
            symbols "on"

      filter "configurations:Release"
            runtime "Release"
            optimize "on"
```

**premake5.lua (ImGui)**

```
project "ImGui"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    files {
        "imconfig.h",
        "imgui.h",
        "imgui.cpp",
        "imgui_draw.cpp",
        "imgui_internal.h",
        "imgui_widgets.cpp",
        "imstb_rectpack.h",
        "imstb_textedit.h",
        "imstb_truetype.h",
        "imgui_demo.cpp",
        "premake5.lua"
    }

    filter "configurations:Debug"
        runtime "Debug"
        symbols "on"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        runtime "Release"
        optimize "on"
```

Then, for my main application, I have this premake file.

**premake5.lua (MyApp)**

```
workspace "MyApp"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
    platforms { "Win32", "Win64" }

project "MyApp"

    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"

    outputdir = "out/%cfg.{buildcfg}"

    targetdir (outputdir)

    IMGUI_LIB = "lib/imgui"
    IMGUI_LIB_BE = IMGUI_LIB .. "/backends"

    files {
        "src/**.h",
        "src/**.cpp",
        "premake5.lua"
    }


    includedirs {
        IMGUI_LIB,
        IMGUI_LIB_BE,
        "lib/glm",
        "lib/glew/include",
        "lib/glfw/include"
    }

    libdirs { "lib/glew/lib/Release/x64"}

    include "lib/imgui"
    include "lib/glfw"
    include "lib/glew"

    links {"opengl32", "GLFW", "GLEW", "ImGui"}

    
     
    filter "configurations:Debug"
      defines { "DEBUG" }
      symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
      defines { "NDEBUG" }
      optimize "On"
```

If anyone knows what I am missing or if there is any information that would make the issue easier to diagnose, please let me know. I greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Is it normal that project "GLFW"/"GLEW" doesn't have source files? are they header only?

Comment: Typo: *`"out/%cfg.{buildcfg}"`* -> `"out/%{cfg.buildcfg}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over your code, it seems that you are linking `"opengl32", "GLFW", "GLEW", "ImGui"` to your `GLEW` target.

Your `project` node includes the scripts, and *then* links to the libraries, which probably activates each project, and leaves the last one activated:

```
project "MyApp"
    -- some stuff here
    include "lib/imgui"
    include "lib/glfw"
    include "lib/glew"
    links {"opengl32", "GLFW", "GLEW", "ImGui"}
```

Change that to something like:

```
include "lib/imgui"
include "lib/glfw"
include "lib/glew"

project "MyApp"
    -- some stuff here
    links {"opengl32", "GLFW", "GLEW", "ImGui"}
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much, I'd never have guessed that made a difference